# MySQL select the condition only if row in column is duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select all LID which fulfill the selected LID. I have a table named LNZ for example like this:

```
+------------+
|    LNZ     |
+-----+------+
| NID |  LID |
+-----+------+
|  1  |    1 |
|  1  |    2 |
|  1  |    3 |
|  2  |    1 |
|  2  |    3 |
|  3  |    1 |
|  4  |    1 |
|  4  |    2 |
+-----+-------+
```

What I want is, to select all entries which contains the NID 1 and 4 in this case. But it could be more than two NID selected.

For the NID 1 and 4 the output should be:

```
+------------+
|    LNZ     |
+-----+------+
| NID |  LID |
+-----+------+
|  1  |    1 |
|  1  |    2 |
|  4  |    1 |
|  4  |    2 |
+-----+-------+
```

If I do this

```
SELECT  NID, LID
FROM    lnz
WHERE   NID = 1 OR NID = 4;
```

I get this wrong result:

```
+------------+
|    LNZ     |
+-----+------+
| NID |  LID |
+-----+------+
|  1  |    1 |
|  1  |    2 |
|  1  |    3 |
|  4  |    1 |
|  4  |    2 |
+-----+-------+
```

It works with following SQL statement, but it isn't variable with the required NID

```
SELECT T1.NID, T1.LID
FROM LNZ AS T1
JOIN LNZ AS T2 ON T1.LID = T2.LID
WHERE T1.NID = 1 AND T2.NID = 4
   OR T2.NID = 1 AND T1.NID = 4;
```

My question now is... How can I change this statement, to make it variable with the number of selected NID?

Feel free to ask if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: Why should skip `1  |  3` record?  because  there is not row  with values: `4  |  3`. Is this correct ?

Comment: Is this a prepared statement,  stored procedure or are you generating the query dynamically?

Comment: Query `SELECT  NID, LID
FROM    lnz
WHERE   NID = 1 OR NID = 4;` has selected the correct records..  Why is `NID 1 | LID 3` a wrong record in your opinon..

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. The only NID rows which should appear are the ones which can be fully paired with other NID rows.  i.e. NID 4 and NID 1 both have LIDs of 1 and 2, whereas NID 2 and NID 3 don't. Likewise, you don't want to include rows where another NID cannot match them.

Comment: @OtoShavadze yes correct

Comment: @NemanjaPerovic i generate it dynamically

Comment: @NiallFH yes this is what I am trying to do

Comment: I see. And if you specify more NIDs, then you only want the rows where the LID is the same for all of them? So, for example, if the specified NIDs are 1,2 and 4, only 3 rows (1,1), (2,1) and (4,1) should be returned?

Comment: @NemanjaPerovic yes this is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try

```
SELECT * FROM LNZ
WHERE NID IN (1,2,4)
AND LID IN (
    select LID from LNZ
    WHERE NID IN (1,2,4)
    GROUP BY LID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
)
```

where in your language that you use to build the query you dynamically set the (1,2,4) to the values of NID you want and you set the count (based on the number of NIDs you want, in my example it is 3), it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  T1.NID, T1.LID
FROM    LNZ AS T1
    JOIN (SELECT  LID
          FROM    lnz
          WHERE   NID = 1 OR NID = 4
          group by lid
          having count(*)>1) sub ON t1.lid=sub.lid
WHERE   (T1.NID = 1 OR T1.NID = 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply (e.g. how the table should be indexed).

Answer (score 0):

@NemanjaPerovic offered nice solution, this solution looks like it, difference is that you can count NID's here, instead of language/application level. Something like this:

```
select * from LNZ 
where NID in(1,2,4)
and
lid in(
    select lid from LNZ 
    where NID in(1,2,4)  
    group by lid
    having count(*) = (select count(distinct NID) from LNZ where NID in(1,2,4) )
)
```